# Gtk3/Gnome 3 colored button: apply ".needs-attention" css styles

Tags: python, button, gtk3, gnome, gnome-3

## Preface

In gnome 3 applications some buttons are highlighted by having a tinted background instead of that greyish color of a normal button. These buttons aren't only colored differently when using the standard Adwaita Theme, but are also implemented in a variety of other themes. Below are examples of a normal button and a colored one respectively for the Adwaita and the Flat Plat Theme.

#### Adwaita

[image: Adwaita normal] [image: Adwaita needs-attention]

#### Flat Plat

[image: Flat Plat normal][image: Flat Plat needs-attention]

## Now to my problem

I would like to be able to also implement these "important buttons" in my Gtk3 applications. During research on how to do that I discovered in the theme files that these "important buttons" have a special CSS class called `needs-attention`. I then tried to set the CSS class of my button to `needs-attention` as well. However that didn't work. I'm still getting a grey standard button. To demonstrate what I did I'm appending a minimal script and a screenshot of the running program. The "Rename" button should be highlighted just like in the screenshot above. How do I do that?

## My Code

[image: Screenshot of script]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Needs Attention Button")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(hbox)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Remove")
        hbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("Rename")
        button.get_style_context().add_class("needs-attention")
        hbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNOME's Adwaita theme has predefined two classes for suggested actions:

- `suggested-action`
- `destructive-action`

You can read it on GNOME Wiki [HowDoI/Buttons](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Buttons):

> While most buttons are gray, it has become more fashionable to
>   emphasize buttons that are the suggested action, by giving them a
>   different color. In the Adwaita theme, the color is blue. ...
>   Recently, another style class for dangerous actions has been added as
>   well: 'destructive-action'. The Adwaita theme uses red for buttons
>   marked as such.

On Adwaita they look like this, respectively:

- [image]
- [image]

The predefined `needs-attention` class, it's a Gtk.Stack/GtkStack child property and it's rendered in a Gtk.StackSwitcher to call for users attention, as described in the [GtkStack API Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html#GtkStack--c-needs-attention):

> ### The “needs-attention” child property
>
> ```
> “needs-attention”          gboolean
> ```
>
> Sets a flag specifying whether the child requires the user attention.
>   This is used by the GtkStackSwitcher to change the appearance of the
>   corresponding button when a page needs attention and it is not the
>   current one.

The resulting visual aid can be seen in `gtk3-widget-factory` program, as a blue dot on the child needing attention (assuming Adwaita theme):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all I got wrong was that I was using the wrong CSS class. The correct one is `suggested-action` instead of `needs-attention`. If I replace that string in my original code I will get the following correct result:

[image]